# Conveying a tkinter button's execution across different classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple graphical user interface using tkinter which gives a blank canvas on which the cursor places a green square wherever it is clicked.

I am trying to code in a *"Clear all"* button at the top of the interface which clears the entire canvas (whilst retaining the cursor's ability to draw squares when it clicks on the canvas again):

```
import tkinter as tk 

class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Button(self, text="Clear all", command=self.clearall).pack(side = tk.LEFT)

    #What the heck do I do here?
    def clearall(self):
        #self._canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
        pass

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Doodle test")
        master.geometry("600x600")
        self._interface = Interface(master)
        self._interface.pack()
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg='white')

        self._canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self._canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.leftclick)

    # And would I need to put something here?
    def plz_run_me_when_clearall_method_is_called(self):
        self._canvas.delete(tk.ALL)

    def leftclick(self, arg):
        d = 10
        self._canvas.create_rectangle([(arg.x, arg.y), (arg.x+d, arg.y+d)], fill="green")


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Ordinarily, this would be a simple task if the entire program was constructed within a single class, e.g.:

```
def clearall(self):
    self._canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
```

Since there are two classes, I cannot call the `.delete(tk.ALL)` method for `_canvas` since it is declared in the `App` class. So how could I convey a button to execute function X which affects item Y from another class?

EDIT: Still trying to think of an appropriate title for this post.

Comment: you could pass `clearall` function to `Interface` in `App.__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple rule of python (not just tkinter) is that, if an object needs a resource in another object, that first object needs a reference to the second object.

That means either passing in the instance of `App` to the instance of `Interface`, or passing in the canvas itself.

### Using tight coupling

For example, you could pass in the canvas this way:

```
class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, canvas):
        ...
        self._canvas = canvas
        ...
    def clearall(self):
        self._canvas.delete(tk.ALL)


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg='white')
        self._interface = Interface(master, self._canvas)
        ...
```

There are many ways to accomplish a similar thing. For instance, instead of passing in the canvas you can pass in the reference to the app itself (eg: `self._interface = Interface(master, self). You could then either make`self._canvas` "public", or you could provide a getter that the returns the canvas.

The potential downside to the above approach is that it tightly couples the two classes together. That is, if `App` some day is remade to draw on an image object rather than a canvas object, `Interface` will also have to be modified since it depends on a specific implementation in `App` (namely, that it does all its work on a canvas).

### Using loose coupling

Loose coupling means that `Interface` doesn't know or care how `App` is implemented, it only knows that `App` promises to provide an API that `Interface` can use. In this way, `App` can completely change its implementation without breaking `Interface`, as long as it continues to provide the same API.

To keep these classes loosely coupled, you need to move add a `clearall` method into `App`. With this, `Interface` doesn't need to know that `App` uses a canvas, it just needs to know that `App` provides a way to clear the drawing surface, no matter what that drawing surface is.

```
class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, app):
        ...
        self._app = app
        ...
    def clearall(self):
        self._app.clearall()


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg='white')
        self._interface = Interface(master, self)
        ...
    def clearall(self):
        self._calvas.delete(tk.ALL)
```